# Trying to read a text file into an array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Firstly, I'm using DEVC++, my goal of this code is to be able to read a text file into an array of structs. My text file is written like this:
animalName:animalType:RegistrationNo:ProblemNo.

My issue with the below code is that it only seems to be running the while loop once.

I have looked up similar code but it uses to_string() and stoi but I don't think DEVC++ runs C++11 so I was wondering if there's an easy fix to my existing code or if there's another way to accomplish reading a text file which is made up of strings and ints

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;

struct Animal
{
   string animalName;
   string animalType;
   int Registration;
   int Problem;
};

int main()
{
   Animal ani[MAX];
   ifstream infile;
   int i = 0;

   infile.open("Animals.txt");
   if (!infile) {
       cout << "Unable to open file";
       exit(1);
   }

   int count = 0;
   while (infile.good()) {
       getline(infile, ani[i].animalName, ':');
       getline(infile, ani[i].animalType, ':');
       infile >> ani[i].Registration, ':';
       infile >> ani[i].Problem, '.';

       count++;
       i++;
   }

   infile.close();
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       cout << ani[i].animalName << " ";
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       cout << ani[i].animalType << " ";
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       cout << ani[i].Registration << " ";
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       cout << ani[i].Problem<< " ";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see which state flag is true? `bad()` and `fail()` could help you figure out the problem.

Comment: It's not exactly the source of your problem, but a loop of the form `while (infile.good())` or `while (!ifile.bad())` or `while (!infile.eof())` is almost always a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

```
infile >> ani[i].Registration, ':';`
```

doesn't read and discard the `':'`, leading to bloody death... Sorry. Leading to a parsing error when

```
infile >> ani[i].Problem
```

tries to turn the `':'` into an integer. This places `infile` into the fail state,

```
while (infile.good())
```

finds that `infile` isn't good, and exits the loop.

You will have to do something along the line of

```
std::string temp;
std::getline(infile, temp, ':');
ani[i].Registration = std::stoi(temp);
```

to read the stream up to the `':'` delimiter into a `std::string` and then turn the `string` into an integer with `std::stoi`.

[Documentation on `std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

That's the bulk of the bug. But...

```
while (infile.good())
```

tests that the stream is good BEFORE reading from it. This allows the stream to fail utterly while reading without any tests before the failed results are used.

```
while (getline(infile, ani[i].animalName, ':') &&
       getline(infile, ani[i].animalType, ':') &&
       getline(infile, temp1, ':') &&
       getline(infile, temp2, '.'))
{ // only goes into loop if everything was read
  // may also have to eliminate a newline here
    ani[i].Registration = std::stoi(temp1);
    ani[i].Problem = std::stoi(temp2); //exception if bad
    i++;
}
```

An even better approach is to make a `>>` operator overload for `Animal` because that lets you write a main loop that looks like

```
while (infile>> ani[i])
{ 
    i++;
}
```

And that's so simple that all rejoice. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for information on writing the `>>` operator and much more general wisdom.

Comment: If you have a `>>` for Animal, you can `std::vector<Animal> ani(std::istream_iterator<Animal>{}, {});` to read it all in a declaration.